# save error: Invalid type: int

Tags: java, int, salesforce, apex-code

```
public int getSelected2()
{
    //selectedAssets.clear(); //
    for(assetswrapper accwrapper : assetsList)
        if(accwrapper.selected == true)
            selectedAssets.add(accwrapper.acc);
    int a;
    a = selectedAssets.size();
    return a;
}
```

When I try to compile the following piece of code, I get this error:

> Save error: Inavlid type:int.

This is in Salesforce. I'm not sure what the problem is?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I supposed you are using `apex` since you tagged the question as salesforce.

**Apex** is not Java, it has not type `int`

Try by using `Integer`

More Apex primitive types: 
http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/langCon_apex_primitives.htm